# Typescript generic extend typeof JSON

Tags: json, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a JSON:

```json
{
  "menus": {
    "main": {
      "title": "Foo",
      "buttons": {
        "chooseSphere": "Btn #1",
        "searchMaster": "Btn #2",
        "balance": "Btn #3",
        "settings": "Btn #3",
        "help": "Btn #4",
        "signUp": "Btn #5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a function that should have autocomplete for buttons according to the menu key.

I have created an interface with generic where the type of key `name` should be the key of the menu buttons

```js
export interface ISubmenu<T> {
  name: keyof T;
  template: MenuTemplate<Context>;
}
```

I have created a function that builds a submenu for one of the menus defined in the JSON object

```js
export const createSubmenus = <K extends keyof typeof localeJSON.menus>(
  menuKey: K,
  options: Array<ISubmenu<typeof localeJSON.menus[K]['buttons']>>
) => {
  const menuLocale = createMenuLocale(menuKey);

  const submenus = [];

  options.forEach((option) => {
    submenus.push({
      text: (context: Context) => menuLocale.getButton(context, option.name),
      action: 'chooseSphere',
      template: option.template,
    });
  });

  return submenus;
};
```

The problem is that it cannot get the keys of specific menu buttons and an error happens in `option.name` (it should be the keys of `main` menu buttons)

[image: Error in VSCode]

The interface should take keys of the `main` menu buttons but it sees the type as a string

How can I improve the generics so it will allow me dynamically take keys for different menu buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by passing typeof menuKey parameter of the function to pass generic type into interface:

```js
export const createSubmenus = (
  menuKey: keyof typeof localeJSON.menus,
  options: Array<ISubmenu<typeof localeJSON.menus[typeof menuKey]['buttons']>>
) => {
  const menuLocale = createMenuLocale(menuKey);

  const submenus = [];

  options.forEach((option) => {
    submenus.push({
      text: (context: Context) => menuLocale.getButton(context, option.name),
      action: 'chooseSphere',
      template: option.template,
    });
  });

  return submenus;
};
```